# Two-line itemeditor for whole row in single-line s:Datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have some DataGrids with pretty standard one-line itemrenderers, but need to use a custom two-line itemeditor for the whole row. I want to/must do this because I cannot edit each cell individually, but need to edit the whole object before I can save it.

I've run into two big problems so far:

1. How to place/display the itemeditor so that it actually works for the whole row?
2. How to force the DataGrid to change the rowheight on the edited entry so that the two-line itemeditor doesn't bleed into the row below?

---

**Basically, what I want is this:**
[image: DataGrid item rollover]
[image: DataGrid item editing]

---

**MyDataGrid:**

```
<s:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" height="100%" width="100%" sortableColumns="false" editable="true" variableRowHeight="true">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="foo" itemEditor="myItemEditor"/>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="bar" itemEditor="myItemEditor"/>

            <s:GridColumn width="24" itemRenderer="myItemRenderer"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

**MyItemEditor:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemEditor xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare():void {
                itemLongname.text = this.data["longName"];
                itemShortname.text = this.data["shortName"];
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Group>
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:TextInput id="itemLongname"/>

        <s:TextInput id="itemShortname"/>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group>
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:Rect width="100%"/>

        <s:Button id="itemSaveButton" label="Save"/>

        <s:Button id="itemCancelButton" label="Cancel"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:GridItemEditor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this helps you :)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65e9f-7fd4

Comment: Ohhh, very nice. Did't stumble over that one during my research about this. Despite having worked my way around it (by manually sizing an itemeditor in the first column to overlap the other columns) I'm having a look at that. Perhaps it will help me to make my solution cleaner. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option : http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Flexicious-30-Release-Grid-Edition.aspx (item number 5).

[image]